# Java - Reflection - Convert to JSON Array

Tags: java, json

i create and set values like the following in java

```
public Class creatObjectWithDefaultValue(String className) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
        DefaultParamValues defaultParamValues = null;
        Class objectClass = null;
        try {
            objectClass = Class.forName(className);
             Field[] fields = objectClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields();

             for(Field f:fields){
                    if(!f.isAccessible()){
                        f.setAccessible(true);
                        Class<?> type = f.getType();

                        if(type.equals(Integer.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.INTEGER);  
                        } else if(type.equals(BigInteger.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.BIGINTEGER);  
                        }else if(type.equals(LocalDate.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.DATE);  
                        }else if(type.equals(Boolean.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.BOOLEAN);  
                        }else if(type.equals(Long.class)){
                            f.set(objectClass, defaultParamValues.LONGVALUE);  
                        }
                        f.setAccessible(false);
                    }
                    //System.out.println(f.get(objectClass));
                }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return objectClass;
    }
```

now i want to convert the return object as `JSON or JSON Array` i tried some thing like this but it throws exception as `The constructor JSONObject(Class) is undefined`

```
System.out.println ( new JSONObject( te.creatObjectWithDefaultValue("com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO") ).toString () );
```

Please help me to correct the mistake.

Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for working with JSON data? Reinventing the wheel is most often error-prone and is only suitable for either education or the case when no library or framework fits your purposes at all.

Now, for **JSON <-> Object** conversion, there is not a single reason not to use a higher level framework, unless you're explicitly trying to investigate Reflection itself.

Answer (score 1):

there is no constructor with the parameter class in JSONObject.

but you could create an object of the class and pass it to the jsonobject constructor:

```
System.out.println ( new JSONObject(te.creatObjectWithDefaultValue("com.hexgen.ro.request.CreateRequisitionRO").newInstance() ).toString () );
```

this only works with classes that have a parameterless constructor

Comment: Understood Philipp how do i convert the Class to JSON Object or Json Array

Answer (score 1):

This is very clear.

```
The constructor JSONObject(Class) is undefined
```

The API → http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html